# mv command Increment a numeric char at the start of folders names that start with >1

Tags: linux, mv

On Ubuntu. the following command needs to change the names of the folders from "n something" to "n+1 something" where n is a number that is bigger than 1.

Below is command (by openai chat) and the error:

`for folder in [2-9]*; do mv "$folder" "$((10#${folder}+1))_${folder#*_}"; done`

Error: `-bash: 10#2 Gálatas+1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "álatas+1")`

Here is the output of the `ls` of the parent directory with names in Spanish :
`'1 Romanos'  '2 G'$'\303\241''latas'  '3 Hebreos'  '4 Santiago'  '5 I Pedro'  '6 II Pedro'  '7 Judas'  '8 Apocal'$'\303\255''psis'`

How can this be done without having to manually `mv` every directory? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have folder names with multiple consecutive spaces, you can try this :

```
for folder in [2-9]*; do 
    read -r number rest <<< "$folder"
    echo mv "$folder" "$((number + 1)) $rest"
done
```

remove `echo` when you are ready to run `mv`.